# How to validate presence of parameter in API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've setup middleware to check for the presence of a required parameter in an API call. The problem is, if the parameter is missing my middleware never gets called. I simply get a generic `404` error because the route couldn't be identified. I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing:

routes.js:

```
router.get('/players/:id/info',
  middleware.params.ensureExist,
  info.index
);
```

/middleware/params.js:

```
var ensureExist = function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.params && req.params.id;
  if (id) {
    return next();
  } else {
    logger.warn('req.params.id required.', { error: 'Missing req.params.id' });
    return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Missing req.params.id' });
  }
};
```

`GET '/players/56/info'` produces the expected response.
However, `GET '/players/info'` just gives me a generic `404` instead of the custom error message above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your middleware will only be called on routes that include the `:id` param, because you have it mounted on `'/players/:id/info'`. You'll need to mount it on `'/players'` in order to match both cases.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo on my part. Fixed now.

Comment: Oops,  that was supposed to be a comment,  not an answer!  I blame my mobile.

Comment: Changed to my actual answer, sorry about that.